# cmd.exe changing directories using a variable

Tags: batch-file

Say my desktop is at "F:/Desktop".
Why is it that in a batch file, this will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set DesktopFolder=F:\Desktop

cd /
cd !DesktopFolder!
```

But this won't:

```
cd /
cd F:\Desktop
```

Comment: I believe your second one should be `cd F:\Desktop`

Comment: I don't believe either way works. First, Windows uses backslash characters as a path separators, and second the way to replace environment variables with their value is to surround them with `%` characters, as in `cd %DesktopFolder%`. Lastly, if you want `cd` to also change the current drive as well as the current directory, you need to use the `/d` option, as in `cd /d %DesktopFolder%`

Comment: good points and info from both comments. Thanx.The forward slashes were just bad typing.

Comment: but the question still stands, and I believe, is valid as edited. I would still like to know why windows lets the second one work.

Comment: I mean the first one! $/%XXX!  They're the same statement, but they're not because the first one works and the second one doesn't. This is just curiosity and not critical to any mission.

Comment: !DesktopFolder! works with delayed expansion enabled. In fact, on my computer, %DesktopFolder% doesn't work with delayed expansion enabled, although I think you have the option on some versions of windows.

Comment: All that you say is correct, except that I wasn't asking why the second one doesn't work. I never expected it to work. But I also didn't expect the first one to work, because it looks just like the second one. But it did work. That's my question. Why does the first one work.

Comment: Does not work for me on Win7. Which version of Windows are you using, and which directory are you executing the batch file from?

Comment: Right you are. Thanks. I must not have tested this enough to make sure I was starting from a prompt from the C: drive, which is what I assumed I was doing. Now that I check, neither works when starting from C:\xxx>. Faith restored. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

martineau answered you as to why the second one doesn't work.

> Lastly, if you want cd to also change the current drive as well as the
>   current directory, you need to use the /d option, as in cd /d
>   %DesktopFolder%

The current directory and the current drive are separate things.

To see it in action open a command prompt (which will likely start at C:\Users\%username%), type `cd F:\Desktop` and notice that you didn't change anything visibly. If you then follow that up with a `F:`, you'll find that the working directory on F: was already changed to Desktop, instead of the root.

The /d option referenced by martineau does both in one shot.

Comment: (Responded in the wrong section, so I'll repeat here:) All that you say is correct, except that I wasn't asking why the second one doesn't work. I never expected it to work. But I also didn't expect the first one to work, because it looks just like the second one. But it did work. That's my question. Why does the first one work? I should have made the intent of my original question more clear.

Comment: Gotchya. I was going to point out that it doesn't work for me, but I see that you've already reached the same conclusion.

Comment: Yup. I  recently moved my desktop to my F: drive, so I was dealing with a little more confusion than usual. :). Regards.